# How can I match my regex for URL (example.net/directory) without HTTP, HTPPS and WWW?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string format with URLs. For example: "first string url is example.com/directory, second URL is http:///example.com/directory and 3rd is [www.example.com/directory"](http://www.example.com/directory%22)

I want to  match my regex exactly for "example.com/directory" without http and www

I am trying the following regex but this is also working for http, https and www.

```
(\S+)(?:com|net|[/])[/](\S+|$)
```

Comment: https://regexr.com/ is super useful resource to design and test regex

Comment: Yes I am using the same tool but unable to create regex for url without http and www https://regexr.com/62s2o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a regex if you can, see if you can parse the url with a dedicated library

This will also help with other TLDs, such as `.net`, `.org`, `.club`.

```py
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urls = ("https://www.example.com/directory", "www.example.com/directory", "example.com/directory")
>>> for url in urls:
...     print(urllib.parse.urlparse("http://" + url.split("//")[-1]))
...
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.com', path='/directory', params='', query='', fragment='')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.com', path='/directory', params='', query='', fragment='')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='/directory', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

To get just the top and second-level domain, you could just `split()` the netloc

```py
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse("http://whatever.example.com").netloc.split(".")[-2:]
['example', 'com']
```

Comment: I understand your point but how would I detect that example.com/directory as url and pass to urls (tuple) but https://www.example.com/directory and www.example.com/directory can be detectable.

Comment: you can detect that it has a `.netloc` and `.path` field, take this as being valid (or at least not invalid), and _then_ split out the real top and second level domains (perhaps `.split(".")[-2:]`?)

Answer (score 0):

To only allow for `http://` and `www.` prefix (only one, if any). Then you can use optional alternatives:

```
^(?:http:\/\/|www\.)?(\w+\.(?:com|net)\/directory)$
```

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/aPtYhc/1

We use a capturing group to only capture the "example.com/directory" of the URL. This means that the RegEx will not capture everything it matches.

Comment: Can we match just first one? (example.com/directory)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you want a RegEx to only match "example.com/directory", then it is this one: `example\.(?:com|net)\/directory`. If you want a RegEx that can ensure that the entire string starts with one of the prefixes (`http://` or `www.`) and then extract the string like "example.com/directory" that follows, then you must use a capture group. This means that your RegEx will match more than you want to extract, but you can simply use the capture group to extract what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This regEx might help.

1 [www.example.com/directory](http://www.example.com/directory)     match:example.com/directory

2 http://example.com/directory  match:example.com/directory

3 example.com/directory         match:example.com/directory

4 example.net/directory         match:example.net/directory

```
(?<=www.)[\w\.\/]+|(?<=http:\/\/)[\w\.\/]+|\w+.com\/\w+|\w+.net\/\w+
```

You could check regEx online here.

https://regex101.com/r/pEmcJP/1